# Кастомизация header шаблона TwentyTwenty

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка, input

Я использую шаблон TwentyTwenty на своем сайте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу вставить вместо `Elementor #7` или `Пример страницы` поле ввода input для Поиска (это значение `placeholder`). Подскажите, что надо сделать для этого (я видел только как редактировать записи: типа "Привет, мир", я искал на [Редактирование шаблона wordpress](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk002XQJBbE-sSmRjXaR9dbJeSPGYcw%3A1600167954833&source=hp&ei=EqBgX-jYMKLqrgSSrIWgBQ&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20wordpress&oq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANOgUIABCxAzoICAAQsQMQgwE6AggAOgQILhBDOgQIABBDUPa-AVj36gFgoP8BaABwAHgAgAFliAGWD5IBBDIyLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab) - не нашел).

P. S. уже нашел [Форма поиска в шапке сайта wordpress](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk02aOhwPghPJQjO34G2NtqHJFCNs_Q%3A1600173151681&source=hp&ei=X7RgX9rFJfKEwPAPmIOyuA8&q=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20wordpress&oq=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20wordpress&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICCEQFhAdEB46AggAOgUIABCxAzoICAAQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOgIILjoICAAQChABECo6CQgAELEDEAoQAToGCC4QChABOgYIABAKEAE6BwgjEOoCECc6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6BAgAEEM6BQguELEDOggILhCxAxCTAjoHCAAQFBCHAjoGCAAQFhAeOgUIIRCgAToHCCEQChCgAToECCEQClD2BFiZyQFg4s4BaAhwAHgAgAGbAYgBjSeSAQUxMC4zNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQc&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwia8Z_ClevrAhVyAhAIHZiBDPcQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)

Comment: Четвёртый аккаунт.

Comment: Это троллинг такой,  что ли? У тебя кнопка поиска правее ссылки Пример страницы.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Я не знаю как разблокировать аккаунт (обязательно черкните как). Во-вторых, это нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @KAGGDesign как разблокировать аккаунт (какие пункты меню интерфейса форума необходимо выбрать)?

Comment: Никак кнопками. Аккаунт блокируется системой за многочисленные минусы. Чтобы его разблокировать, надо дать несколько удачных ответов на вопросы, которые будут приняты пользователями. То, что ты делаешь сейчас (новые аккаунты), называется обходом правил сообщества и наказывается перманентным баном.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно создать дочернюю тему и в ней изменить header.php

1. Создать папку twentytwenty-child в папке wp-content/themes/
2. В новой папке создать следующие файлы

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Twenty Child Theme
Theme URI: #
Description: Twenty Twenty Child Theme
Author: #
Author URI: #
Template: twentytwenty
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
```

functions.php

```
<?php
/* enqueue scripts and style from parent theme */        
function twentytwenty_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwenty_styles');
```

3. Скопировать header.php из папки wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/ в папку wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child/
4. В файле wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child/header.php

Найти фрагмент

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) || ! has_nav_menu( 'expanded' ) ) {
                        ?>

                            <nav class="primary-menu-wrapper" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Horizontal', 'twentytwenty' ); ?>" role="navigation">

                                <ul class="primary-menu reset-list-style">

                                <?php
                                if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {

                                    wp_nav_menu(
                                        array(
                                            'container'  => '',
                                            'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
                                            'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        )
                                    );

                                } elseif ( ! has_nav_menu( 'expanded' ) ) {

                                    wp_list_pages(
                                        array(
                                            'match_menu_classes' => true,
                                            'show_sub_menu_icons' => true,
                                            'title_li' => false,
                                            'walker'   => new TwentyTwenty_Walker_Page(),
                                        )
                                    );

                                }
                                ?>

                                </ul>

                            </nav><!-- .primary-menu-wrapper -->

                        <?php
                    }
```

Заменить его на

```
 <?php get_search_form( $echo = true ); ?>
```

5. Админ - внешний вид - Темы. Активировать тему "Twenty Twenty Child Theme"
6. Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в коде у вас написано `'items_wrap' => '%3$s'`, чему равно `%3$s`? Также что означают индексы массива `'match_menu_classes'`, `show_sub_menu_icons'` и `'walker'` (я смотрел https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_pages, но не нашел ничего, кроме walker)?

Comment: Вам нужно удалить весь это фрагмент в header.php и поставить  <?php get_search_form( $echo = true ); ?>

Comment: Просто я хотел понять как оно соотносится с тем что я нашел https://sdelaemblog.ru/kak-dobavit-formu-poiska-na-sajt-wordpress
https://pro-wordpress.ru/nastrojka-wordpress/kak-sdelat-poisk-po-sajtu-na-wordpress.php
https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_search_form
https://bloggood.ru/wordpress/forma-poiska-dlya-wordpress.html/
https://wpincode.com/vyezzhayushhaya-forma-poiska-v-wordpress/

Comment: я в интернете нашел, что дают команды `has_nav_menu`, `esc_attr_e`, `wp_nav_menu`, `wp_list_pages`. Но не понял общего смысла  кода и как он соотносится с кодом, приведенным на вышеуказанных страницах (можете выбрать одну из них)?

Comment: "Elementor #7 или Пример страницы" из Вашего вопроса - это верхнее меню. в ответе я описал как изменить верхушку под себя из дочерней темы. если нужно изменить цвет кнопки - переопределите стили в style.css в дочерней теме